# I haven't used single quotes on a VARCHAR column but query still executes?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, ssms, sqldatatypes

The below query filters on two columns in the `WHERE` clause. Both columns are of `VARCHAR` datatype. Purely by mistake I ran the query without putting single quotes around the `column2` values and it ran successfully and return the correct result set.

Query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE column1 = 'QTR12345678'
  AND column2 IN (120012, 220015)
```

Note: if I only search on `column2` then I get the expected error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value...

It seems like the SQL engine implicitly converts the value from numeric to `varchar` is this instance. Why?

(I'm using SQL Server 2012 SP2)

Comment: I could only imagine this working if you had columns with the names `Q120012` and `G220015`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff All colum, table names and values are made up. The real values do not correspond to any column name within the DB. Note: I i add single quotes to column2 values and remove them from the column1 value the query also runs.

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: @JacobH Hi Jacob. A working example? The code above is as close to one as I can provide. The DB i'm using belongs to the company i work for and I cannot provide specific information. I do not currently have any public DBs set up from which I could provide one either. You could easily replicate this in your own DB as it's a very simple query. Cheers, Corey.

Comment: Hi Corey, I cannot replicate it using your code. http://rextester.com/MNHF35329 If you can't provide a working example this post is guaranteed to never receive an answer as what you have described is impossible. Cheers, Jacob.

Comment: Jacob, Apologies as I noticed a difference between the example I mocked up and the real one I had. I've updated my question to Reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer to this question is that when you are comparing two different datatypes together, the SQL engine implicitly converts one of the values based [Data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

In my example, I'm comparing an integer value to VARCHAR values from my table column. As the values stored in column2 are numeric (they only contain numbers), the SQl engine can convert these values to INT and compare them to the INT values in my WHERE clause. As such, I get the correct result set.

Comment: . . You changed the values in the question.  They were not originally numeric.

Answer (score 0):

There is one situation when something like this can happen: When there is no rows that match `P_1` for a `WHERE P_1 AND P_2`. `P_2` isn't even evaluated then, as a `false AND P` is false regardless of `P`.

Consider this example:

```
CREATE TABLE elbat
             (nmuloc_1 VARCHAR(8),
              nmuloc_2 VARCHAR(8));

INSERT INTO elbat
            (nmuloc_1,
             nmuloc_2)
            VALUES ('A',
                    'aaa'),
                   ('B',
                    'bbb'),
                   ('C',
                    'ccc');

SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE nmuloc_2 = 123;
-- Fails with "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'aaa' to data type int."

SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE nmuloc_1 = 'X'
             AND nmuloc_2 = 123;
-- Succeeds
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdf21b3cf45206eb702898a1aae17634)

In the second `SELECT` query there is no rows for `nmuloc_1 = 'X'`. So `nmuloc_2 = 123` isn't evaluated and the query succeeds. (With an empty result set.)

In the first, `nmuloc_2 = 123` is the only predicate. It has to be evaluated and the query fails with an conversion error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case I had results return (two rows). I can confirm that the column2 filter worked as expected as if completely removed I get 3 rows. I've since found the answer to my question. Please see the answer I've left if interested.